# In Corda, can persisted ContractStates encode commands?

Tags: corda

I have some ContractState, and there are two commands that can 'delete' the state (mark it as historic, with no new state to replace it) - let's say 'Delete' and 'Revoke', which have different real-world consequences.

I can still see the historic states in the vault, right? How can I determine which command deleted the state? I suppose I could add some enum to the state: 'Active|Deleted|Revoked', and then move the state from S(Active) -> S(Deleted|Revoked) -> Historic. But that seems clunky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, you could determine which command was used to consume the state by checking the transaction that consumed the state.

However, there is currently no non-deprecated API for viewing the contents of the node's transaction storage as a node owner. This is because in a future version of Corda, we expect transaction resolution to occur within a secure guard extension (SGX). This will affect which transactions are visible, and Corda therefore cannot commit to a stable API for viewing the contents of the node's transaction storage.

If you're willing to use the deprecated `internalVerifiedTransactionsSnapshot`/`internalVerifiedTransactionsFeed` API, you could do something like:

```
val (_, vaultUpdates) = proxy.vaultTrackBy<ContractState>()

vaultUpdates.toBlocking().subscribe { update ->

    update.produced.forEach { stateAndRef -> 
        val newStateTxId = stateAndRef.ref.txhash
        val transactions = proxy.internalVerifiedTransactionsSnapshot()
        val transaction = transactions.find { transaction -> transaction.id == newStateTxId }!!
        val commands = transaction.tx.commands
    }
}
```

An alternative would be to add a status field to the state, and updating the status field instead of marking it as consumed when "deleting" it. For example:

```
class MyState(val expired: Boolean): ContractState {
    override val participants = TODO()
}
```

Comment: Can I have one transaction that takes a state from non-historic|ACTIVE to non-historic|REVOKED to historic? I'm surprised this doesn't exist - I'd imagine that if states represent trades, for instance, that a node would want to know _how_ it was made historic...

Comment: That wasn't doesn't exist, sorry? To have two state transitions, you'd need two transactions in any case.